# java validations with dates

Tags: validation, open-source, java

I have a java web application that has to deals with resource management.

**FOr Example**

```
Dept      Min     Max   Resource    Effective Date      Last Date
 HR        1       3      Alex        08/19/2013        12/31/2013
 HR        1       3      Adam        08/19/2013        12/31/2013

 IT        2       5      Jade        08/19/2013        10/31/2013
 IT        2       5      Robert      11/01/2013        12/31/2013
 IT        2       5      Lisa        08/19/2013        12/31/2013
```

I have different departments which has preset min/max employees I can allocate as a manager. So HR- dept has min of 1 and max of 3, I have allocated 2 from today to end of year.

In IT dept I have allocated a partial dates for Jade and robert to count them as 1 for entire period. Lisa for end-to end. which together is 2 which is in the min/max range.

Basically, the bottom line is at any point of time I have to make sure allocation will not violate the min/max rule. **So, I want suggestions about how to validate these kind of scenarios in java application. Any open source API you found useful.**

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you basically want to find out which intervals overlap. Concerning dates, I normally tend to use http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/ since it has a very clean and nice API compared to out-of-the-box java Date.

Joda time also offers Intervals and a method to check if intervals overlap: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html#overlap(org.joda.time.ReadableInterval)

Nevertheless it didn't work for me as I wanted to check on a per-day basis, thus I had to implement it myself, using Joda time Intervals as base objects:

```
public static boolean checkInteraction(Interval one, Interval another) {
    return  ((one.getEnd().equals(another.getStart()) || one.getEnd().isAfter(another.getStart())) &&
            (another.getEnd().isAfter(one.getStart()) || another.getEnd().equals(one.getStart())));
}
```

Having this in place, you can go through the intervals and check if they overlap/interact and check if it exceeds your max number.